# Sometimes flash.message displays and sometimes it doesn't

Tags: grails-2.0

We've encountered a situation where sometimes a flash.message displays correctly, but sometimes it doesn't show up at all.  I would appreciate any tips on how to troubleshoot.

Here is what the code looks like in our controller:

```
log.debug("missing required fields ${errorMsg}")
flash.error = errorMsg
...
log.debug("leaving moveToDraft with flash.message: ${flash.message} and 
    flash.error: ${flash.error}")
redirect(controller: 'challengeManagement', action: 'show', id: 
    challenge.challengeNumber)
```

Here is what the view code looks like:

```
<g:if test="${flash.message}">
    <div class="message"><%=flash.message%></div>
</g:if>
<g:if test="${flash.error}">
     <div class="error"><%=flash.error%></div>
</g:if>
```

This code always works for me on my development box and the test systems, but for our QA person,  about half the time the flash message does not display. From the log.debug statements I have confirmed that it is getting set and has a value on leaving the controller method.  Looking at the 'view source' from the page, it is clear that the divs do not exist.  They never got written out, which means that the test conditions must have failed.

Now a 307 redirect does happen after the above redirect.  So, that might be a problem given the flash object's limited scope... except that I also get the 307 redirect and I always see the flash.message/flash.error on the page.

Is there any way I can debug the flash object so that I can see when it is cleared out?  Also,  is there a page that describes the mechanism in more detail? (I read that it depends on cookies, but I don't see it in the request cookie list).  Any other ideas or thoughts on how to troubleshoot?

My next step would be to rewrite without using the flash object, but my concern is that I don't understand what the problem is, and we use flash objects everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question just in case it helps someone else.  The problem was indeed the 307 redirect.

For every other browser except this particular browser version,  the 307 redirect did not cause the flash object to clear.  And in this particular browser version, it only caused the flash to clear a portion of the time, say 40%.  I don't know why that is so, but I traced it beyond a doubt. (I suspect a race condition between two Apache rewrite rules, but I'm not investigating further.)

The 307 was created by rewrite rules in our Apache server, which redirected any incoming http request to be an https request.  So the solution for us was simple:  make our initial requests already be https, so that they don't run afoul of the Apache rewrite rules. There were two ways to do this: 1) create a full uri and then redirect using the uri rather than the usual controller/action parameters

```
String baseUrl = ContextUtil.grailsBaseURL(true)
String uri = "${baseUrl}/challengeManagement/show/${challenge.challengeNumber}"
redirect (uri: uri)
```

2) add a spring security config variable that causes it to use https rather than http

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.definition = ['/**' : 
      'REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL']
```